# How to Convert String in a Text File into Array in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, file

I have text file containing quotes inside single quotes. They are "not" one liners. eg there may be two quotes in same line, but all quotes are inside single quotes like

```
'hello world' 'this is the second quotes' 'and this is the third quoted text'
```

how can I create an array and making each quoted text an element of the array. I've tried using

```
declare -a arr=($(cat file.txt))
```

but that makes it space separated. assigns each word an element in the array

Comment: `eval arr=($(cat file))`?

Comment: eval?... nice try though

Comment: Unless the quoted strings can contain newlines, I would just put each string (sans quotes) on a separate line, and use `readarray` to populate your array.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do that without security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson ahhh? you've got to be kidding right?

Comment: [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56695505/26428) I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you have bash v4.4 or later, you can use `xargs` to parse the quoted strings and turn them into null-delimited strings, then `readarray` to turn that into a bash array:

```
readarray -t -d '' arr < <(xargs printf '%s\0' <file.txt)
```

If you have an older version of bash, you'll have to create the array element-by-element:

```
arr=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' quote; do
  arr+=( "$quote" )
done < <(xargs printf '%s\0' <file.txt)
```

Note that `xargs` quote syntax is a little different from everything else (of course). It allows both single- and double-quoted strings, but doesn't allow escaped quotes within those strings. And it probably varies a bit between versions of `xargs`.